# How to run dotnet command from command line?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, command-line-interface

I Installed Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 from setup file[setup folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtrhL.png)

and selected the following components [visual studio dialog1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUFR2.png) [visual studio dialog2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5z5t.png)

and after that mY control panel shows these components installed [controlpanel1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2REv.png) [control panel2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnJVf.png)

as control panel shows i have .NET Framework sdk installed i am not able to use dontnet command from command line even in regedit program i checked the path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\ there is no FrameworkSDK folder [regedit screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1trP5.png)

the System variable Path Component contains the following path [System variable screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlvVm.png)

what path  should i add so that dotnet command runs from Command Line

Comment: You need to install the .NET Core SDK: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.0.3-windows-x64-installer That's not part of Visual Studio by default.

Comment: Additionally, please write text directly in the question rather than showing images for everything. (For example, a registry entry is just text - so include it as text...)

Comment: thanks for a quick response,just to make it clear i included the screenshot. What is the difference between sdk that i have installed and coresdk won't i be able to run my c# programs from command line by just providing the path for dotnet since i have the sdk installed

Comment: No, the .NET SDK isn't the same as the .NET Core SDK. It's not clear whether you actually *need* the .NET Core SDK at all - we don't know what you're trying to achieve. If you're happy building desktop applications, you can build and run those without .NET Core.

Comment: I just wanted to practise c# fundamentals so i thought if i could do it in visual studio then i could also achieve the same thing from command line since i had the sdk installed thats why i wanted to enquire if i could do it with the tools already installed or would i have to install something else as i was following Microsoft .Net Guide in which dotnet command was mentioned.

Comment: Well you can use msbuild and csc from the command line without installing the .NET Core SDK, but if you want to use the dotnet CLI, you need to install the .NET Core SDK. They're two related but distinct ecosystems.

Comment: @JonSkeet AFAIK Visual Studio 2017 include .NET Core SDK as an optional component, which you can choose at installation time.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Yes, but the OP has VS2015. I didn't want to introduce that extra piece of complexity/nuance.